# Run AWS Lambda to create AMI of the instance in a different region

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ami

I am using AWS Lambda to create AMIs on daily basis for my EC2 prod instance. All my infra setup in in a Mumbai region but **AWS doesn't support Lambda functionality in Mumbai region yet**.

So, I chose Singapore region to setup Lambda. I followed the links [create-AMI](https://gist.github.com/bkozora/724e01903a9ad481d21e) and [cleanup-ami](https://gist.github.com/bkozora/d4f1cf0e5cf26acdd377) to create and delete AMIs after retention period, however, this works only if I have the instance in Singapore region with the specified tags in the code.

My question here is: how can I create AMI for Mumbai instances whilst my Lambda is in Singapore region?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are encountering? Please include a clear problem statement in your question. All you should have to do is set the region you want the AWS SDK code to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the region when initializing the boto client :
`ec = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-south-1')`

Comment: I am pretty new to python boto. This Worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to share-copy the AMI from one account to another. Here is the solution:

```
# Copying image from src_account to dest_account
SRC_ACCOUNT_ID = '111111'
DEST_ACCOUNT_ID = '222222'
IMAGE_ID = '333333'
SRC_REGION = 'us-west-1'
DEST_REGION = 'us-east-1'

# Create CrossAccountole Role in src_account which will give permission to operations in the acount
sts = boto3.client('sts')
credentials = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::'+SRC_ACCOUNT_ID +':role/CrossAccountRole',
    RoleSessionName="RoleSession1"
)['Credentials']
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=SRC_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
)

# Access the image that needs to be copied
image = ec2.Image(IMAGE_ID)

# Share the image with the destination account
image.modify_attribute(
    ImageId = image.id,
    Attribute = 'launchPermission',
    OperationType = 'add',
    LaunchPermission = {
        'Add' : [{ 'UserId': DEST_ACCOUNT_ID }]
    }
)

# We have to now share the snapshots associated with the AMI so it can be copied
devices = image.block_device_mappings
for device in devices:
    if 'Ebs' in device:
        snapshot_id = device["Ebs"]["SnapshotId"]
        snapshot = ec2.Snapshot(snapshot_id)
        snapshot.modify_attribute(
            Attribute = 'createVolumePermission',
            CreateVolumePermission = {
                'Add' : [{ 'UserId': DEST_ACCOUNT_ID }]
            },
            OperationType = 'add',
        )

# Access destination account so we can now copy the image
credentials = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::'+DEST_ACCOUNT_ID+':role/CrossAccountRole',
    RoleSessionName="RoleSession1"
)['Credentials']

# Copy image to failover regions
ec2fra = boto3.client('ec2', DEST_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
)

# Copy the shared AMI to dest region
ec2fra.copy_image(
    Name = 'MY_COPIED_IMAGE_FROM_OTHER_ACCOUNT',
    SourceImageId = image.id,
    SourceRegion = SRC_REGION
)
```

There it is, simple :)

Read about commands [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)